# Headings in on-topic page need fixing

Tags: bug

In the [on-topic page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), space missing between `###` and the heading text:

See here:

> ##If your question is about:
>
> Raspberry Pi hardware, including GPIO and other related electronics.
> Raspberry Pi peripherals. Software specific to the Raspberry Pi.
> Operating Systems built for the Raspberry Pi. Materials published or
> provided by the Raspberry Pi Foundation. … then you’re in the right
> place to ask your question!
>
> ##But please note that the following is off topic

I'm in the process of fixing the [on-topic page for 3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is a mess, so that's how I discovered that fact...

Comment: It *does* support Markdown headers; they just need to have a space between the `###` and the rest of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising this issue. Seems like that formatting issue has been there a while...

I've just gone and fixed the issue, as Glorfindel has said putting a space between the hashtags and the text does the trick.

Comment: While you are at it you could convert *an unusual amount of "off-topic" questions* to English -  *an unusual  NUMBER*. I know this not uncommon these days, but grates on those old enough to have learned grammar.